@DataJpaTest & @SpringBootTest querying src/main/resources database instead of src/test/resources database
Im trying to thoroughly understand Spring Boot, especially testing.
I want all tests to run against the database in application.properties inside src/test/resources regardless of the active profile. But for some reason it only queries src/main/resources databases.
I created the following profiles for now (Maybe the names don't make sense):

tdd
stage
production

I have created two Databases with the same schema and functions through script files:

MythicalLearn
MythicalLearnTest

I also have a separate Data.sql file inside src/test/resources/db/Data.sql
I have a local Postgres database running & since I am using Postgres, I don't feel the need for any test containers or H2, I just created another database on the same instance for testing locally, Is this acceptable ?
As far as I know, everything in src/test/resources should be used for tests but somehow all tests are running against whatever database is in the active profile.
For some reason, all @DataJpaTests and @SpringBootTests are finding the Data.sql script inside src/test/resources/db/Data.sql,
But for some reason, it is running tests against the database defined in the active profile inside src/main/resources file.
I have only added the code I feel is necessary for this question, but will happily edit this and provide more details.
Here is the code:
SQL
TRUNCATE serverappsplayground.DummyEntity RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE ;
INSERT INTO serverappsplayground.DummyEntity (name, key, value, x, y, z)
VALUES
('DE-Name 1', 'key-1', 'value-1', 65, 33, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 2', 'key-2', 'value-2', 47, 96, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 3', 'key-3', 'value-3', 22, 34, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 4', 'key-4', 'value-4', 77, 56, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 5', 'key-5', 'value-5', 89, 17, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 6', 'key-6', 'value-1', 4, 78, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 7', 'key-7', 'value-2', 13, 8, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 8', 'key-8', 'value-8', 67, 10, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 9', 'key-9', 'value-9', 56, 2, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 10', 'key-10', 'value-10', 99, 43, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 11', 'key-11', 'value-11', 65, 33, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 12', 'key-12', 'value-12', 47, 96, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 13', 'key-13', 'value-13', 22, 34, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 14', 'key-14', 'value-14', 77, 56, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 15', 'key-15', 'value-15', 89, 17, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 16', 'key-16', 'value-16', 4, 78, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 17', 'key-17', 'value-17', 13, 8, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 18', 'key-18', 'value-18', 67, 10, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 19', 'key-19', 'value-19', 56, 2, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000)),
('DE-Name 20', 'key-20', 'value-20', 99, 43, FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1000));

Configuration:
application.yml
spring:

    # Set the application name and description:
    application:
      name: "SpringBootWebMvcJavaFoundation"
      description: "This is the fundamental foundation project for Spring Boot"
    main:
      keep-alive: true

  # Setting the profile
    profiles.active: stage

    # Enabling virtual threads
    # This is extremely important in order to maximise performance and make the most of Java 21
    threads.virtual.enabled: true

    # Data access layer

    jpa:
      hibernate:
        # This property is extremely important as I want to remove Spring Boot making queries with those underscores by default:
        naming.physical-strategy: "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl"

        # Here we make sure Spring Data JPA does not mess around with my database as I don't want it too,
        # It makes sure there are no ddl statements in any profile
        ddl-auto: none

    test:
      database:
        replace: none

application-tdd.yml:
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      # Adding the classpath prefix to all paths,
      # and then following the path as normal works for tests + when app context is loaded
      # Note: Schema generation does not  need to happen everytime, I can also manually load the schema,
      # This makes tests slow, so I must simply aware, anytime changes are made too Schema or functions,
      # Either uncomment this to be safe or remember and manually modify the schema with psql,

      #schema-locations: classpath:db/Schema.sql,classpath:db/Functions.sql
      data-locations: classpath:db/Data.sql
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MythicalLearnTest
  jpa:
    show-sql: 'true'
testpropertyexists: 'yes'

application-stage.yml
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      #schema-locations: classpath:db/Schema.sql,classpath:db/Functions.sql
      #data-locations: classpath:db/Data.sql
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MythicalLearn"

application.properties in src/test/resources:
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MythicalLearnTest
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:db/Data.sql

Test Code
@DataJpaTest base class:
@org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class DataJpaTest {
    
}

class DummyJpaServiceDbTest extends DataJpaTest {

    private DummyJpaService dummyJpaService;

    @Autowired
    private DummyJpaRepo dummyJpaRepo;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        dummyJpaService = new DummyJpaService(dummyJpaRepo);
    }

    @Test
    void works() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    void getAllDummies() {
        assertEquals(
                20,
                dummyJpaService.getAllDummies().size()
        );
    }

    @Test
    void getDummyById() {
        assertEquals(
                "key-7",
                dummyJpaService.getDummyById(7).get().getKey()
        );
    }

    @Test
    void createDummy() {
        DummyEntity entity = new DummyEntity();
        entity.setKey("key-222");
        dummyJpaService.createDummy(entity);
        assertEquals(21, dummyJpaService.getAllDummies().size());
    }

    @Test
    void updateDummy() {
        DummyEntity entity = dummyJpaService.getDummyById(7).get();
        entity.setName("UPDATED DE7");
        dummyJpaService.updateDummy(entity);
        assertEquals("UPDATED DE7", dummyJpaService.getDummyById(7).get().getName());
    }

    @Test
    void deleteDummy() {

        DummyEntity entity = dummyJpaService.getDummyById(20).get();
        dummyJpaService.deleteDummy(entity);
        assertEquals(19, dummyJpaService.getAllDummies().size());
    }

    @Test
    void deleteDummyById() {
        DummyEntity entity = dummyJpaService.getDummyById(20).get();
        dummyJpaService.deleteDummyById(entity.getId());
        assertEquals(19, dummyJpaService.getAllDummies().size());
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/Data.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
public class SpringBootJavaApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}

    class DummyApiServiceIntegrationTest extends SpringBootJavaApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private String basePath = "/dummy-entity-api";

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Checking and hoping the real database is loaded for tests")
    void getAllDummies() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
            get(basePath + "/dummies")
        ).andReturn();

        assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).isNotBlank();

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing the response returns the 20 lists that are in the dummy data")
    void getAllDummiesObjects() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
            get(basePath + "/dummies")
        ).andReturn();

        //Use the arrrays.asList because mapper returns an array:
        List<DummyEntity> dummyEntityList = getDummyListFromJson(
            result.getResponse().getContentAsString()
        );

        assertThat(dummyEntityList.size()).isEqualTo(20);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("When id not found then we get 404")
    void getByIdNotFound() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
            get(basePath + "/{25}", 25)

        ).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("When id found then it is 200")
    void getByIdFound() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
            get(basePath + "/{1}", 1)

        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing that it creates a new entity")
    void testCreates() throws Exception {
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = new DummyEntity();
        dummyEntity.setName("DE-Created By Spring Boot test");
        dummyEntity.setKey("key-21");
        dummyEntity.setValue("value-21");
        dummyEntity.setXYZ(1,2,3);

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
                post(basePath + "/create")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(dummyEntity))
            )
            .andReturn();

        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus()).isEqualTo(201);

    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Here i am testing that the extra entity is added, but then on each load it is reset")
    void testExtraEnttityIsAdded() throws Exception {
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = new DummyEntity();
        dummyEntity.setName("DE-Created By Spring Boot test");
        dummyEntity.setKey("key-21");
        dummyEntity.setValue("value-21");
        dummyEntity.setXYZ(1,2,3);

        mvc.perform(
                post(basePath + "/create")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(dummyEntity))
            )
            .andReturn();

        //Not a very readable expression, but later I can learn
        assertThat(
            getDummyListFromJson(
                mvc.perform(
                        get(basePath + "/dummies")
                    )
                    .andReturn()
                    .getResponse()
                    .getContentAsString()
            ).size()
        ).isEqualTo(21);



        //Getting the list so I can see it should be 21:

    }

    /**
     * Keeping a private function that gets a List from JSON String,
     * So I do not have to repeat myself multiple times:
     */
    private List<DummyEntity> getDummyListFromJson(String jsonList) throws Exception {
        return Arrays.asList(
            mapper.readValue(
                jsonList,
                DummyEntity[].class
            )
        );
    }



}

Now, I have two separate databases, but when I run the tests while in the staging profile, it finds the Data.sql script in test/resources, but for some reason, does not run the tests against the test database:


I have truncated the tables many times and the same thing happens
How do I get all tests to only run against the test database regardless of the profile ?
Is this even possible ?
Or perhaps, what I am trying to do is silly, and there is a better work flow ?
I can't help but think, this is one of those things that is so straight forward that its not even mentioned, but I am not getting it.
I will appreciate any advice

What happens now is that the keys from both files (src/test/resources/application.properties and src/main/resources/application.yml) are merged, so the spring.profiles.active key is present in your tests.
Rename your src/test/resources/application.properties to src/test/resources/application.yml. This will override the src/main/resources/application.yml. So now only the keys from src/test/resources/application.yml will be present in the tests.

Thanks, Is this just because of the extension I guess

Yes. If you use same extension, they have same name, and whichever is first in the classpath will be loaded and the second ignored. When you run the tests, the test-classes directrory will be before the main classes directory in the classpath. If they have different extension, and therefore different names, both will be loaded. It's the same as the class files resolution.

Thanks, The only issue with this is that, I have to completely repeat myself for a lot of properties that I want to be common between tests and the regular application.yml, Just one last question if I may, is it considered best practice to have the testing environment completely seperate, or just have a seperate profile for tests / tdd, then find some way to only run tests against the test database ? I got this to work and i accepted your answer,

It's difficult to say what is best practice. I would say put the keys, that are common for all envs, in src/main/resources/application.yaml and override keys subset per env with profiles, like you are doing now. The keys subset to be overriden for the tests will be in src/test/resources/application-test.yaml. And set the active profiles via env-var, or via runtime arguments, not via the yaml files. For convenience the test profile you can active via annotation - @ActiveProfiles("test"). That way there will be no duplication.

This is incredibly helpful thanks, mainly what I’m looking to do is have a separate test profile but even if I am on another profile, I want to be able to run my tests against the test database even if it’s a different profile, thank you for responding
